# Problem with the allocated partition memory

Tags: partitioning, memory, resize

I installed ubuntu 12.04 using wubi on to a 60GB partition. I installed Qt sources, which are a couple of GB in size, but once I start commpiling it started complaining about lack of memory.

I checked the size of the partition and it said it has 30GB remaining, but then checked the properties of the home folder  and it said 9.9GB remaining.

I'd appreciate , if someone could explain and help me to sort this out.

I have attached a screenshot below.

Thank you in advance.

Some details of the system are as follows.

[image]